# Show that $\int_0^{c} \frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{c^{nm+k}}{nm+k}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

$$\int_0^{c} \frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{c^{nm+k}}{nm+k}$$

where $k,m \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}:= \mathbb{N} \setminus \mbox {{0}}, c\in(0,1) $

Can I maybe use here a speciel series? I stil don't know at which point should I start.

Comment: Are you sure about the denominator?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it and that is the exercise

Comment: I got now the hint that prove at first that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{nm}=\frac{1}{1-x^m}$$

Comment: You missed a dx I think

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$ \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i$$

$$ x \to x^m$$

$$ \frac{1}{1-x^m} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{im}$$

Multiply this by $x^{k-1}$,

$$ \frac{x^{k-1} }{1-x^m}  = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{k+im-1}$$

Comment: Could u help me who does taking the integral of $\frac{x^{k-1} }{1-x^m}  = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{k+im-1}$ indicate $\int_0^{c} \frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{c^{nm+k}}{nm+k}$?

Comment: did you mean why? Basically the idea is as long as your in the 'domain of convergence' you can switch integral and sums